# Why can't I use ArrayList<String> as a parameter for a generic ArrayList<E> method?

Tags: java, generics

I am learning about generics so I made a simple java program so I can learn how they exactly work. But now I am stuck with this program because I can't see why it won't work.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        strings.add("A");
        strings.add("B");

        printList(strings);
    }

    public static <E extends List<E>> void printList(ArrayList<E> l)
    {
        for (E obj : l)
        {
            System.out.println(obj.toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why is `E` required to extend `List<E>`?

Comment: Because you've specified `E` to extend `List<E>`. Which is not true for `String`.

Comment: Your formal argument is effectively `ArrayList<? extends List<E>>`.  Either replace the parameter type with `E`, or drop the bound on `E`.

Comment: What you've specified with your method generics is that the argument passed to the method will be an `ArrayList<List<E>>`. A list of lists, basically. Then you pass it a list of `String`. Just take out the `<E extends List<E>>` part and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your generic parameter `E` should not extend list. if `E extends List<E>` then you should be expecting `List< List<> >`.

Your method should look something like:

```
public static <E> void printList(List<E> list) {

    for (E obj : list) {

        System.out.println(obj);
    }
}
```

Notes:

- Use meaningful argument names like `list` not `l` so that code maintainers understand your code
- `System.out.println(object.toString())` can be simplified to `System.out.println(object)` because `toString()` will be called automatically
- If you want you code to be more robust, make the parameter a `List<E>` so you can accept all `List<E>` objects such as `LinkedList<E>` and all other implementations.

Answer (score 6):

`<E extends List<E>>` is almost certainly not what you want.  What that says is that your element type is a list of itself.

Instead, write just `<E>`.